# How to avoid compiling Frameworks while building in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-simulator

I am trying to create a Custom Framework that builds in iOS Simulator.

> I have got some libraries that are meant to build only in Real
> Devices. I want to avoid compiling those particular frameworks while
> my Framework is being built for Simulator.

Is there a way we can avoid compiling certain libraries during the Build Phase?

My wild guess is we can try avoiding them using a script in Build Phases but I am not sure about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Make the framework `optional` not `required` in `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries`
- In `Build Settings > Linking` in `Other Linker Flags` create a flag for option `Any iOS Simulator SDK` and add value `-ObjC -weak_framework <the framework to ignore>`
- And in code check for build target like this `#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR.`

[image]